# Mapped drive using in Task scheduler

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to download documents from SharePoint library and placed in network drive. For that I created Mapped drive. I need to run this from server using Task scheduler as it need to download around 400 GB data(it will run for 5 hrs.).

Task scheduler is not identifying the Mapped Drive, Mapped drive is working when ran EXE.

- I cannot UNC path as there are lot of nested folders, Folder path will
  cross 256 characters.
- Run Only when User Login as it need to run for 5+ hrs.
  I developed the code in c#.

Need help on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is the scheduled task configured to use the same user account as you're testing with manually? Is it configured to load the user profile?

Comment: @Mathias, how do you control whether the user's profile is loaded or not? Is this related to `Run whether user is logged on or not` / `Do not store password` (selecting the latter would definitely prevent network access)?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I need to use Admin account only